# avoid direct variable mutation with onPush change detection

Tags: javascript, angular

So I am aware that when you use the `onPush` change detection strategy - the page only updates on indirect object mutation so for example

```
user: User = {
  name: 'Steve'
}

// ...

// This will not trigger the change detection since it is a direct mutation
updateUser() {
  user.name = 'James' 

}

// This will update since its storing a new object
updateUser() {
  this.user = {
    name: 'James'
  }
}
```

Now my question is say I have a `boolean` variable like so

```js
loading = true;
```

now when I change loading to false

```js
this.loading = false;
```

It does not trigger the change detection.. so how do I indirectly update a single value to trigger the `onPush` change detection??

I am aware of `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` but is there another way? Am I missing a crucial piece to the puzzle??

Comment: change in primitive types cause change detection even with onPush strategy, here change in loading should reflect in child component without using detectChanges

Comment: Smokey Dawson - Is it resolved ??

Answer (score 0):

numbers, booleans, strings, null and undefined are primitive types so updating a boolean **should** trigger the change detection, whether you're in Default or OnPush change detection strategy

Can you reproduce your issue in a stackblitz or provide more code on your issue ?